# Make Panel visible using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, panel

I have a Panel with property, Visible set to False

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUpload" runat="server" Visible="False" />
```

and i try to make it visible using javascript as code below

```
document.getElementById('<%= Panel1.ClientID %>').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

but it's not working, any idea guys?

Answer (score 8):

Setting Visible="false" makes the panel not to render in the generated HTML. If you want to make it show/hide in the client side, you need to make it Visible="true" and use a CSS class/in the style attribute having "display" property with the value "block" or "none" as required.

Comment: This is exactly what I suspected, +1

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this with zero ASP experience but a lot of JS/HTML/CSS experience so bear with me if I am completely wrong...

I would say that the `Visible="False"` tag is not equivalent to the CSS `style="visibility:hidden;"` therefore that JS call will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display asp controls you need to use the property

```cs
ClientVisible
```

Example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="someId" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="someIdClient" ClientVisible="False" />
```

As mentioned in a previous post the attribute

```
Visible="False"
```

leads to not rendering the control.

In order to access the hidden control via Javascript you simply type:

```
function myFunction(){ someIdClient.SetVisible(true)
```

Comment: ClientInstanceName and ClientVisible are not properties of standard Web Form controls

Answer (score 1):

I tried .style.visibility = 'visible' and visible="true" and .style.display = 'block' 
and .style.display = 'inline' all those thing does not work. 
but if you write .style.display = 'none'  it work.
any body know the solution 
Please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I answering with almost zero ASP experience, like Flash84x :-)

It seems that in asp, when you set "Visibile=false", the panel is not created.

And if you would like to use custom JavaScript and not the .NET facility to display, hide a panel you should apply a style directly in the tag like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlUpload" runat="server"
  Style="visibility:hidden;background-color:#CC9999;
```

color:#FFFFFF; width:200; height:200;
      border:solid 1; padding:10">
    .....

And then it will rendere somthing like this in html
:

```
<div id="pnlUpload" class="text" style="visibility:hidden;
```

background-color:#CC9999; color:#FFFFFF; width:200; 
    height:200; border:solid 1; padding:10"> 
        .....

```
</div>
```

And of course the corresponding javascript would be:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
document.getElementById('pnlUpload').style.visibility = 'visible';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put your panel in a div
and change the style using the following way

```
<div>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUpload" runat="server" Visible="False" />
</div>
```

javascript

```
function visible()
{
document.getElementById('<%=pnlUpload.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use visibility use this..

```js
document.getElementById("<%=myPanel.ClientID%>").style.display = "none"; //not visible
document.getElementById("<%=myPanel.ClientID%>").style.display = "inline"; //visible
```